# Serve the contents of text files in a webpage

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that takes parameters and prints data onto the screen from a text file stored somewhere on the internet..

For example, you might request

```
http://example.com/resource.php?id=5
```

Say that request is an attempt to access a text file resource, so I go ahead and find the URL to the text file, read it, and then display it on the page:

```
$f = fopen($url, "rb");
echo stream_get_contents($f);
```

However the formatting isn't correct; it's missing new-lines. I tried using `r` mode, but the output was still the same.

Then I remembered that new-lines in text files (`\n`, `\r\n`, possibly others) aren't treated as line breaks in HTML, so I went and replaced all occurrences of `\r\n` and `\n` to `<br>`

And now the new lines appear properly. However, I noticed there were large patches of empty space here and there, and realized it was because those particular text looked like `<this>` and `<that>`

At this point I realize this doesn't seem like a good idea, especially since browsers know how to render text files anyways. I could simply re-direct them to the URL of the text file I guess, but I am planning to provide functionality that will query multiple files for input, so a redirect might not work too well.

How do I serve contents from a text file reliably?

Comment: consider using readfile()

Comment: @nl-x I looked up `readfile` and then decided to go with `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to tell the browser that you are serving text and not HTML then:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```